# How to fetch data from database related to key using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner, and I want to show the value data into the input field related to the key but I am very confused that how can I show the value data into the input field so please if you have an idea please help me thanks.

**Database table**

Setting table https://ibb.co/jGFX4t2

I want to show a value data in this field, please see https://ibb.co/Mh08c9b

**Settings Model**

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    protected $table="setting";
    protected $fillable =['id','key','value'];
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function setting()
{
    $setting=Settings::all();
    return view('admin.setting.setting',compact('setting'));
}
```

**HTML view**

```
<form method="post"  action="{{route('update.setting')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"    >     
    @csrf
    <div class="card-box">
        <div class="panel panel-heading">
            <h3>Update Settings</h3>
        </div>        
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="mt-3">
                <input type="file" name="logo_image" class="dropify"  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 mt-3">
                <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Contact Number*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contact_number"  value="{{  }}"   class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="col-lg-5 mt-3">
                <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Contact Email *</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{    }}" class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-10 mt-3">
                <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Location *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="location" value="{{   }}" class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div>    
            <div class="col-lg-5 mt-3">
                <h3> Social Links:</h3>
                <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Facebook *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="facebook" value="{{  }}" class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-5 mt-5">
                <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Twitter *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="twitter" value="{{}}" class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-6 mt-3">
                <div class="group-form">
                    <label>Linkedin *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="linkedin" value="{{}}" class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-7 mt-3">
                <div class="group-form ">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light col-lg-2">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>   
    </div> <!-- end card-box -->
</form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models)?  A few minutes reading and you wouldn't need to ask this question. Your Controller query returns a collection of settings (even if there is only 1).  So you need to either iterate over them, or if there is really just 1, take the first.  Then it is just `{{ $setting->Contact_Number }}` etc to display values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this code.

```
         {{ $setting->Where('key', 'Contact_Email')->first()->value }}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
{{ $setting->firstWhere('key', 'Contact_Number')->value; }}
{{ $setting->firstWhere('key', 'Contact_Email')->value; }}
{{ $setting->firstWhere('key', 'Location')->value; }}
```

etc

When you use Eloquent `Model::all()`, it returns a collection to the blade view.

Therefore you can use [firstWhere](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-first-where) to find the key value.

Comment: I updated my answer, changed `where` to `firstWhere`. That should return the first found item rather than the collection

Comment: please check again error thanks https://flareapp.io/share/RmrDZq7z

Comment: Are you sure that key `Contact_Email` exists?

Comment: Can you explain why you're using this approach?

Comment: exactly the Contact_Email key exists.

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation